# Magento 1.8 "Load More Product" Button Not working

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript

Am creating a button for **Load More Product**. I refer this link to create this [Reference Link](http://www.uxrim.com/technical/2013/11/26/ajax-loading-of-product-collection-in-project-listing-page-magento/).

And am using **coolbaby** theme in my store. In **coolbaby** theme this code not working properly, but i tried in default **rwd** theme it's working.

> Path: app/design/frontend/coolbaby/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

This is the code:

```
<button id="load-more-products" class="button btn-primary">Load more products</button>
    <script>
        function sendLoadMoreProductsRequest(url) {
        new Ajax.Request(url, {
            onSuccess: function(response) {
                //Create dummy element
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = response.responseText;
                //refresh the page class element
                $$('.pages')[0].innerHTML = $(div).select('.pages')[0].innerHTML;
                //append the list to the existing product list
                $$('.category-products')[0].innerHTML += $(div).select('.category-products')[0].innerHTML;
                //check if there are more products to be loaded or not
                if(!$(div).select('.next.i-next')[0]){
                    $('load-more-products').style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function callbackFunc(e) {
        if($$('.next.i-next')[0]){
            var nextPageUrl = $$('.next.i-next')[0].readAttribute('href');
            sendLoadMoreProductsRequest(nextPageUrl);
        }
        else{
            //hide button
            $$(e.currentTarget).hide();
        }
    }

    //Assigning click event to the button which triggers the "next" link
    $('load-more-products').observe('click', callbackFunc);
    </script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
        //check if there are more products to be loaded or not
        if(!$$('.next.i-next')[0]){
            $('load-more-products').style.display = "none";
        }
        function testScroll(ev){
            if($$('.scroll-to-top')[0]){
                console.log(window.pageYOffset);
                if(window.pageYOffset>400){
                    $$('.scroll-to-top')[0].style.display = "block";
                }
                else{
                    $$('.scroll-to-top')[0].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
        window.onscroll = testScroll;
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Please any one help to fix this error. Or suggest me for `load more` product extension.

**Note**: Show `load more` button in list page, after click this button only load other products.

Comment: load more or infinite scroll extension ??

Comment: infinite scroll extension

Comment: i tried above code, it working in default  `rwd` theme. But it does't working in `coolbaby` theme.@MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE : as user wants extension That's why I suggest this extension

please install this extension for infinite scroll, I have tested and use this extension in couple of site and this extension works very good

https://marketplace.magento.com/strategery-strategery-infinitescroll2.html

Comment: I tried this but in this extension shows `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Mediafallback' not found in /home/mwinwm/public_html/includes/src/Etheme_Coolbabyconfig_Helper_ConfigurableSwatches_Mediafallback.php on line 8` in front end

Comment: ok let me check the extension code

Comment: `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/strategery-infinitescroll.xml` go to this file and comment this code `<reference name="product_list.name.after">
            <block type="core/template" name="product_list.infinitescroll" template="strategery/infinitescroll/swatches.phtml"/>
        </reference>`

Comment: Is this right `<!-- <reference name="product_list.name.after">
            <block type="core/template" name="product_list.infinitescroll" template="strategery/infinitescroll/swatches.phtml"/>
        </reference>-->`

Comment: yes right.................

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57330/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-murtuza-zabuawala).