# Strategery - InfiniteScroll Not Working in in magento 1.8.1 and where to paste strategery-infinites‌​croll.xml file

Tags: magento-1.8, product

Am download the `Strategery - InfiniteScroll` and installed in my store.

**(I'm just copy and paste the files to my store)**.
1st i got a error like

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Mediafallback' not found in /home/mwinwm/public_html/includes/src/Etheme_Coolbabyconfig_Helper_ConfigurableSwatches_Mediafallback.php on line 8

Then am asking the query in `stackoverflow` that link here [Magento 1.8 "Load More Product" Button Not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170419/magento-1-8-load-more-product-button-not-working)

After that i got the answer to clear the error. I just command the lines in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/strategery-infinites‌​croll.xml`

```
<!--<reference name="product_list.name.after">
            <block type="core/template" name="product_list.infinitescroll" template="strategery/infinitescroll/swatches.phtml"/>
    </reference>-->
```

But still now product not loaded in `list` page. i refer this link https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento-InfiniteScroll/wiki/Installation-under-a-different-package---theme but am not understand.

Am using `coolbaby` theme. Where i want to paste `strategery-infinites‌​croll.xml` 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/` or `app/design/frontend/coolbaby/default/layout`